# python numpy.fft.rfft: why is when NFFT included or not, outputs are very different

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to understand to the meaning of NFFT in numpy.fft.rfft. But I get confused why when NFFT included or not, the outputs get very different. Please see the example below.

```
numpy.fft.rfft([0, 1, 0, 0, 4.3, 3, 599], 8)
array([ 607.3         +0.j        ,   -5.71421356+600.41421356j,
   -594.7         -4.j        ,   -2.88578644-597.58578644j,
    599.3         +0.j        ])

numpy.fft.rfft([0, 1, 0, 0, 4.3, 3, 599])
array([ 607.3         +0.j        ,  369.55215218+472.32571033j,
   -133.53446083+578.34336489j, -539.66769135+261.30917157j])
```

Comment: The list `[0, 1, 0, 0, 4.3, 3, 599]` contains 7 items. As `numpy.fft.rfft([0, 1, 0, 0, 4.3, 3, 599], 8)` is called, the array is padded with a zero, as detailled in the doc of [numpy.fft.rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html). Hence, the first DFT is that of the array `[0, 1, 0, 0, 4.3, 3, 599,0]`: it is of length (n/2)+1=5 since n=8. The second DFT is of length .(n+1)/2=4 since n=7.

Comment: thanks I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT is an efficient implementation of the [Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), which is a discrete function of frequency. It is also related to the [Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform), itself a continuous function of frequency. More specifically, the DFT corresponds exactly to the DTFT evaluated at the discrete frequencies of the DFT.

In other words, when computing a Discrete Fourier Transform with `numpy.fft.rfft`, you are essentially sampling the DTFT function at discrete frequency points. You can see this by plotting transforms of different lengths on the same graph with the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 0, 0, 4.3, 3, 599]

# Compute the DTFT at a sufficiently large number of points using the explicit formula
N = 2048
f = np.linspace(0, 0.5, N)
dtft = np.zeros(len(f), dtype=np.complex128)
for n in range(0,len(x)):
  dtft += x[n] * np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*f*n)

# Compute the FFT without NFFT argument (NFFT defaults to the length of the input)
y1 = np.fft.rfft(x)
f1 = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(x))

# Compute the FFT with NFFT argument
N2 = 8
y2 = np.fft.rfft(x,N2)
f2 = np.fft.rfftfreq(N2)

# Plot results
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(f, np.abs(dtft), label='DTFT')
plt.plot(f1, np.abs(y1), 'C1x', label='FFT N=7')
plt.plot(f2, np.abs(y2), 'C2s', label='FFT N=8')
plt.title('Magnitude')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(f, np.angle(dtft), label='DTFT')
plt.plot(f1, np.angle(y1), 'C1x', label='FFT N=7')
plt.plot(f2, np.angle(y2), 'C2s', label='FFT N=8')
plt.title('Phase')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have a followup question on the rfftfreq (I am new to signal processing), how do you know in the above example that frequency ranges from 0 - 0.5 (the sampling rate is assumed to be 1?) ? If I set the sampling rate to be 16000 Hz, what should be the corresponding rfft (np.fft.rfftfreq(N2, d = 1.0/16000))??

Comment: A full spectrum would cover the range `-0.5*sampling_rate,+0.5*sampling_rate`. For real valued signals the FFT is symmetric. This symmetry is exploited by `rfft` which only returns the non-redundant half of the spectrum, thus cover from `0,0.5*sampling_rate` (which is what `rfftfreq` returns). When no sampling rate is specified `rfftfreq` assumes a sampling rate of 1. To specify a different sampling rate, you have to specify `d=1/sampling_rate` as you correctly noted.

Comment: how does rfft infer the sampling rate? it seems there is no place in the function call to specify the sampling rate?

Comment: do you mean the function numpy.fft.rfft(a, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None)[source] infer sampling rate? but there is no input argument in fft.rfft to specify sampling rate.. this is where I am confused... fftfreq is a different function where you can sample rate.. i am also confused how numpy.fft.rfft and numpy.fft.rfftfreq is related/linked

Comment: sorry I thought you were talking about `rfftfreq`. `rfft` does not infer sampling rate, as the definition of the FFT does not depend on the sampling rate but provide results for frequencies in a normalized equidistant frequency space. `rfftfreq` is to be used to get the corresponding frequencies of each bin from that `rfft` result.